# How can I edit the wingpanel calendar applet?

Tags: wingpanel, themes

I want to edit the wingpanel **calendar applet** to make it similar to **Gnome calendar**. I do not want to change the color, rather want to have some spaces between the days and make the current **date selection** to be **round** with blue color something like in the picture below:

[image: Same like this]

Anyone knows how to do it? At least the file path to that applet.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is in the `wingpanel-indicator-datetime` package. If you want to change the widget, you can get the source package and edit the source (in `src/Widgets/calendar`).